# Arduino Nano 3.0 and Arduino Uno Benchmarks

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, atmega328

What are the benchmarks (MIPS) of an Arduino Uno (ATmega32P) and Arduino Nano 3.0 (Atmega328) @ 1.6MHz?

Answer (score 2):

ATmega16U4/ATmega32U4, ATmega48A/PA/88A/PA/168A/PA/328/P, ATmega2560, and numerous other Atmel AVR 8-Bit microcontrollers have an instruction set typically with “135 Powerful Instructions – Most Single Clock Cycle Execution” per datasheets.

That is, many of the AVR instructions, including almost all of the logic and arithmetic instructions, execute in 1 cycle.  A fair number of memory access instructions take 2 cycles.  A few instructions (eg JMP) take 3 cycles, and some (RCALL, CALL, RET, RETI, et al) take 4 or 5 cycles.  Others (eg SBRC) take 1, 2, or 3 cycles, depending on operand values and whether a branch occurs that disrupts the pipeline, which is shallow.  For an overview, see the instruction set summary in any AVR-part datasheet. For details, see Atmel's [AVR Instruction Set Manual, doc0856 at atmel.com](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf).

Overall, the average instructions per second in a typical compiled C program probably is between 1.5 and 2, so a 16 MHz system might do 8 to 11 MIPS on average, while carefully tailored do-nothing code can easily achieve 16 MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 16MzHz?

Benchmarks are [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products/Compare).

Comment: I checked the page out, but It did not answer my questions. I want to know how many instructions per second (IPS) can the microcontrollers preocess  at their 16MHz clock speed.